# VueJs changing text-animation does not work on iOS devices

Tags: css, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have an animation that is supposed to change the text infinitely and runs for 7 seconds, the issue is it doesn't work on iOS devices.

```
<template>
  <div class="J-container">
  <p>Discover your next location for your <span class="changetext"></span></p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    
}
</script>

<style scoped>
.J-container p {
  font-size: 2.7rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  max-width: 600px;
  line-height: 4rem;
}

.changetext::before {
  content: '';
  animation: effectchange 7s infinite;
}

@keyframes effectchange {
  0% {
    content: 'Video Shoot'
  }

  33% {
    content: 'Events'
  }

  66% {
    content: 'House Party'
  }

  100% {
    content: 'Video Shoot'
  }
}
</style>
```

The above code in action could be found [here](https://lookaam-front.vercel.app/), and it does not work on iOS devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, animation on the `:before` & `:after` pseudo is not supported on the iOS Safari Browser. (ref. [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/?search=%3A%3Abefore))

[image: ::before & ::after animation support on safari ios]

Since it is not supported, you could make use of JavaScript to achieve something similar instead.

Here, in the below code, I am toggling the word declared in the `wordDir` array, and later, if the counter hits the max length, then we reset back to 0.

```js
const toggleWord = document.querySelector('p span');
const wordDir = ['Word 1', 'Word 2', 'Word 3'];
let counter = 0;

setInterval(() => {
  if(counter > (wordDir.length - 1)) {
    counter = 0;
  }

  toggleWord.textContent = wordDir[counter];
  counter++;
}, 1000);
```

```css
p {
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Hello World! <span>Word 1</span></p>
</div>
```